# Update individual partial views on load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view with several partial views. On load, I would like to change the background color for each partial view based on the value of a boolean property.  This boolean is part of the view model for the partial views.

The problem I'm having is trying to get the jquery selector for the specific partial view's dom element.

```
<div class="input-group-wrapper">
 <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive, new {id = "activeChanged"} )
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsActive, "Active")
                </label>

            </div>
  </div>
```

Code in the partial view :

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function () {

    setAddressActiveInactive(@Json.Encode(Model.IsActive));

});
</script>
```

Function that sets the background color:

```
function setAddressActiveInactive(isActive) {
if (!isActive) {
    $("#activeChanged").closest(".input-group-wrapper").attr("style", "background-color: #D3D3D3 !important");

}else {
    $("#activeChanged").closest(".input-group-wrapper").attr("style", "background-color: #f8f8f8 !important");
 }
}
```

So basically when the root view loads initially, if a partial views "IsActive" property is true, to set it to another color, and visa versa.

Answer was instead of using javascript to set this, to use razor syntax to set the style based on the value of IsActive

```
@{
var style = !Model.IsActive ? "background-color:#D3D3D3 !Important" : "";
}
```

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript for this (instead of conditionally applying a class name)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke You mean change the class of the "inner-group-wrapper" based on the IsActive property?  How would I do that?

Comment: Yes (and it can be a simple `if` block, or a conditional `?:` operator)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you!